# get data from txt file and display in a multiline text box

Tags: c#, for-loop, textbox, while-loop

I have a text box called: blogPostTextBox and a file called: blogMessage.txt

This blogMessage.txt contain the 3 texts called

- Message1
- Message2
- Message3

I want to read the data from that txt file and display the data in the blogPostTextBox using either a for loop or a while loop. Also I am required to use System.Environment.NewLine at the end of each message so that each message is displayed on a separate line in blogPostsTextBox.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blogPostsTextBox.Text = "";
        string blogMessage = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + 
                                 "/App_Data/blogMessages.txt");
    }
}
```

How do I continue the codes to make it work?..Thank you guys!

Comment: please clarify - "his blogMessage.txt contain the 3 files called -Message1 -Message2 -Message3" - how can a file contain files?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/blogMessages.txt";
string blogMessage = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadLines(path));
blogPostTextBox.Text = blogMessage;
```

`File.ReadLines` returns `IEnumerable<string>` with lines from file (i.e. there would be your three messages). Then I concatenate lines with `String.Join` - it adds new line after each line which was found in text file.

BTW why you can't simply assign content of file to textbox?

```
blogPostTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

UPDATE (with loop)

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/blogMessages.txt";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(path))    
    builder.AppendLine(line);

blogPostTextBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: how you do it with a loop...? :)

Comment: @PéBin Why does it have to be a loop? To be precise, why does it have to be a loop that you write? There is a perfectly fine, well optimized loop inside string.Join().

Comment: sorry. this is for one of my workshot that they asked me to use a while or a for loop...:(

Comment: So you're asking us to do your homework without even showing the will to try? Did you search the web for "C# for loop"?

Comment: i spend like an hour. searching for it already......but thanks for ur comment..:)

Comment: @PéBin NOTE: when building strings (especially in a loop) use StringBuilder, as I have shown in updated example above

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: can i use string ??insteead

Comment: @PéBin can you use a string instead? I think you should try. FYI strings can be concatenated with `+` operator